# grep file with a large array

Tags: grep, gzip, zcat, map-files

Hi i have a few archive of FW log and occasionally im required to compare them with a series of IP addresses (thousand of them) to get the date and time if the ip addresses matches. my current script is as follow:

```
#input the list of ip into array
mapfile -t -O 1 var < ip.txt   while true
do
    #check array is not null
    if [[-n "${var[i]}"]] then  
    zcat /.../abc.log.gz | grep "${var[i]}"
    ((i++))
```

It does work but its way too slow and i would think that grep-ping a line with multiple strings would be faster than zcat on every ip line. So my question is is there a way to generate a 'long grep search string' from the ip.txt? or is there a better way to do this

Comment: What's an *"FW log"* please? How does `ip.txt` file look? How does `abc.log.gz` look?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. One thing is that using cat is usually slightly inefficient. I'd recommend using `zgrep` here instead. You could generate a regex as follows

```
IP=`paste -s -d ' ' ip.txt`
zgrep -E "(${IP// /|})" /.../abc.log.gz
```

The first line loads the IP addresses into `IP` as a single line. The second line builds up a regex that looks something like `(127.0.0.1|8.8.8.8)` by replacing spaces with `|`'s. It then uses `zgrep` to search through `abc.log.gz` once, with that `-E`xtended regex.

*However, I recommend that you do not do this.* Firstly, you should escape strings put into a regex. Even if you know that `ip.txt` really contains IP addresses (e.g. not controlled by a malicious user), you should still escape the periods. But rather than building up a search string and then escape it, just use the `-F`ixed strings and `-f`ile features of `grep`. Then you get the simple and fast one-liner:

```
zgrep -F -f ip.txt /.../abc.log.gz
```

Comment: after some checking, apparently you need // instead for it to work      (${IP// /|})

Comment: Thanks, updated. I tested the original and it worked... with two IP address. Your change is needed to support 3+, as `/` will only replace the first space rather than all (as required).

Comment: A friend reminded me of the `-F`ixed strings feature. New solution should be much better (though it doesn't technically "build a search string").